# Users unable to edit multi-user calendar events

Tags: permissions, calendar

The problem:

Users are unable to edit multi-user calendar events, despite being given correct permissions (or so I believe...). For example, one user creates an event on their calendar, I want it so another user can edit that event.

It works only if I give the editing user the Modify All Data permission, but I don't want to do that.

What I've tried:
- Getting the creator of the event to grant Full Access to the editing user under My Personal Information > Calendar Sharing.
- Ensuring the calendar event has the "Related To" and "Name" fields defined.
- Giving the user permissions for Edit Events and Edit Tasks.

None of those make any difference.